# How do I make the message collector only be run by the person who executed the command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, collectors

I have this bot, and the bot itself uses a collector in order to collect data from user input. However, whenever someone runs this command to input their own data, someone else can come in and type in anything before the other user can send their message, and the bot will collect that one instead.

**Here's an example:**

```
User1: !collect
Bot: What do you want to collect?
User2: A
User1: B
Bot: Collected (A)
```

If **User 2** sent a message before **User 1** while the collector is running, then the bot will collect what **User 2** has inputted instead of **User 1, who is the person that ran the command.**

So I've tried handling this by modifying the filter and adding in a logical `AND`:

```
const filter = m => m.content.toString() && m.author.id; 
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({
  filter,
  time: 10000,
});
```

Apparently, this doesn't seem to help and the bot will continue to collect what **User 2** has sent instead of **User 1** during the collection process.

Or doing the same thing above but I used `m.content.match()` instead of `.toString()`.

Another thing I tried doing is an odd way to handle it by creating a role with the user ID, making the bot give the role then if the person has that role the collector continues, if not, it just ignores it before at the end of the collection it'll delete the role. That didn't work either.

I was considering making a set to store user ID but that would just result in the same thing as making a new role for it right?

So how do I make the collector *only* collect the message sent by the person who typed the command?

**Rest of code:**

```
 collector.on("collect", async m => {
      if(m.content.toString() == '') {
        message.channel.send("No");
        collector.stop();
      }
  if(!fs.existsSync(`./guild/${message.guild.id + '<@' + message.member.id + '>'}/${args.join(" ")}guild.txt`)) {
    message.channel.send("No info found")
    await fs.writeFile(`./guild/${message.guild.id + '<@' + message.member.id + '>'}/${args.join(" ")}guild.txt`, m.content.toString(), 'utf8', function (err) {
         if (err) throw err;
         });
         collector.stop();
       }
      let guildName = m.content.toString();
      
      if(fs.existsSync(`./guild/${message.guild.id + '<@' + message.member.id + '>'}/${args.join(" ")}guild.txt`)) {
        await fs.writeFile(`./guild/${message.guild.id + '<@' + message.member.id + '>'}/${args.join(" ")}guild.txt`, guildName, 'utf8', function (err) {
         if (err) throw err;
         });
         message.channel.send("Information edited");
         collector.stop();
       }
     }); //Closes start collector
```

**Bot Version:** V13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m.content.toString() && m.author.id` only checks if there is some `content` and if there is an author ID. This filter will always return `true`.

You want to check if the collected message's author is the same as the author of the command. If the message you receive in your event listener is `message`, the following should work:

```js
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
```

I'm not sure why you use `m.content.toString()` though.

Comment: Its mainly to use to store the message that the user sent while the collector is running in a file. Though let me try this.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to work, I get the same exact result. 

I've included the rest of the collector code above if needed.

Comment: That's weird. I'm pretty sure it should work. The ` collector.on("collect",` part is not needed. Can you post the whole file on a site like pastebin.com and send the link here, so I could take a look at it?

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/JmNTUZi4

Comment: But you use `const filter = m => m.author.id` only. That will always return `true` because there is always an `author` with an `id` and that's a truthy value. If you check my answer, it's `const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id`.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that crucial detail that you wrote which was so large I would've been hit by a plane several times